# Delay in for loop-android

Tags: android, for-loop

I'm new to android programming and I have a simple question. I have a random number, nr and I generate this number of ImageViews in the same location. Now, I want to apply an animation to each of these images, but not in the same time.

Let's say I want the first image to start moving at sec 0, then image2 at sec 2 and so on.

I have the images in an array, imb_items[].

```
for(int j=0; j<nr;j++){
imb_items[j].startAnimation(translateAnim);
 ????? how can I put here the delay?
}
```

I'm trying for a long time to do this, but I just can't do it with handlers or threads...I think I don't get the concept.
I would be very thankful if somebody would help me understand and give me a sample code that will work in my specific case.

thank you!

```
public class MyActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements OnClickListener {

    private TextView mCalculatorDisplay;
    private Boolean userIsInTheMiddleOfTypingANumber = false;
    private CalculatorBrain mCalculatorBrain;
    private static final String DIGITS = "0123456789.";
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("@###########");
    Animation anim_translate;
    public double valoare, produs, scor = 0;
    int printfirst, printsecond;
    Handler mHandler = new Handler();
    int[] idMultiple = new int[]{6, 5, 3, 4, 2};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);

        //Img.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        //android.view.Display display = ((android.view.WindowManager)getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();

        Animation translateAnim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MyActivity.this, R.anim.translate);

        DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
        int height = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
        int width = displaymetrics.widthPixels;

        int dpHeight = (int)(displaymetrics.heightPixels / displaymetrics.density );
        int dpWidth = (int)(displaymetrics.widthPixels / displaymetrics.density );
        ImageView imb1=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ImageView1 );



        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Spiridusii lui Mos Craciun pregatesc jucariile pentru copii.",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Ei au observat ca unele jucarii sunt  incomplete. Ajuta-i sa comande piesele lipsa!",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();



        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), height+"inaltime"+width,
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), dpHeight+"inaltime"+dpWidth,
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        RelativeLayout Layout=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.rel_banda);

        ImageView banda=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.banda);


        mCalculatorBrain = new CalculatorBrain();
        mCalculatorDisplay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Raspuns_user);

        df.setMinimumFractionDigits(0);
        df.setMinimumIntegerDigits(1);
        df.setMaximumIntegerDigits(2);

        findViewById(R.id.b0).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.b1).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.b2).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.b3).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.b4).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.b5).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.b6).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.b7).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.b8).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.b9).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.buttonClear).setOnClickListener(this);

        Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                {
                    valoare = Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(mCalculatorDisplay.getText()));


                    genereaza_imagini();


                    check_answer();

                }
            }
        };
        mHandler.post(runnable);


        //genereaza_imagini dinamic de la una la 9 imagini de un anumit tip

    }


    //max poate fi 5 sau 9



    public void genereaza_imagini() {


        final TextView et1, et2;
        et1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.printfirst);
        et2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.printsecond);


        int nr1 = random(5);
        printsecond = random(9);
        printfirst = idMultiple[nr1 - 1];
        produs = printsecond * printfirst;
        et1.setTextSize(13);
        et2.setTextSize(13);
        et1.setText("nr piese lipsa:" + printfirst);
        et2.setText("nr jucarii:" + printsecond);

        et1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        et2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        ImageView imb1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ImageView1);
        ImageView imb2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ImageView2);
        ImageView imb3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ImageView3);
        ImageView imb4 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ImageView4);

        ImageView imb5 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ImageView5);
        ImageView imb6 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ImageView6);
        ImageView imb7 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ImageView7);
        ImageView imb8 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ImageView8);
        ImageView imb9 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ImageView9);
        final ImageView[] imb_items = new ImageView[]{imb1, imb2, imb3, imb4, imb5, imb6, imb7, imb8, imb9};


        for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++) {

            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp;
            lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

            DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
            getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
            int height = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
            int width = displaymetrics.widthPixels;

            int dpHeight = (int) (displaymetrics.heightPixels / displaymetrics.density);
            int dpWidth = (int) (displaymetrics.widthPixels / displaymetrics.density);
            lp.leftMargin = dpWidth / 2 - dpWidth / 10;

            lp.topMargin = dpHeight / 4;

            imb_items[j].setLayoutParams(lp);
            imb_items[j].getLayoutParams().height = 30;
            imb_items[j].getLayoutParams().width = 30;


            imb_items[j].setImageResource(0);
            imb_items[j].setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        final int i = printsecond;  // cate imagini din cele 9


        if (nr1 == 1) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Omizilor le lipsesc 6 picioare.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
                imb_items[j].setImageResource(R.drawable.obj1);
                imb_items[j].setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


            }
        }

        if (nr1 == 2) {


            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Florilor le lipsesc 5 petale. ",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
                imb_items[j].setImageResource(R.drawable.obj2);
                imb_items[j].setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


            }
        }


        if (nr1 == 3) {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Papusilor le lipsesc 3 nasturi. ",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
                imb_items[j].setImageResource(R.drawable.obj3);
                imb_items[j].setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


            }
        }
        if (nr1 == 4) {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Masinilor le lipsesc 4 roti. ",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
                imb_items[j].setImageResource(R.drawable.obj4);
                imb_items[j].setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


            }
        }
        if (nr1 == 5) {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Robotilor le lipsesc 2 antene. ",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
                imb_items[j].setImageResource(R.drawable.obj5);
                imb_items[j].setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            }
        }

        final Animation translateAnim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MyActivity.this, R.anim.translate);

        Thread thread = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                while (true) {
                    try {


                        for(int j=0; j<i;j++){
                            imb_items[j].startAnimation(translateAnim); ???????????????????????????????????????????

                         Thread.sleep(2000);
                        }


                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        Log.v( "tag", "local Thread error");
                    }
                }
            }
        };
        thread.start();


    }



    public int random(int max) {
        Random r = new Random();
        int random = r.nextInt(max) + 1;
        return random;
    }

    public void check_answer() {

        Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                valoare = Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(mCalculatorDisplay.getText()));
                verifica();

            }

        });
    }
    //functie care afiseaza la onCreate, cand apas pe buton 2: nr1, nr2, raspuns corect nr1*nr2

    public void verifica() {

        final TextView et1, et2;
        et1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.printfirst);
        et2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.printsecond);
        TextView Scor = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Scorul);
        if (produs == valoare) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Raspunsul este corect! :)",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            Log.v("Produsul este corect=", String.valueOf(produs));

            scor = scor + 50;

            Scor.setText("Scor:" + scor);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Raspunsul este gresit! :(",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            Log.v("Produsul nu este corect=", String.valueOf(produs));
            scor = scor - 50;
            Scor.setText("Scor:" + scor);
        }


// ca sa actualizeze automat text view-ul raspuns user la 0.0

        if (userIsInTheMiddleOfTypingANumber) {

            mCalculatorBrain.setOperand(Double.parseDouble(mCalculatorDisplay.getText().toString()));
            userIsInTheMiddleOfTypingANumber = false;
        }

        mCalculatorBrain.performOperation("C");
        mCalculatorDisplay.setText(df.format(mCalculatorBrain.getResult()));

        genereaza_imagini();

    }


    // mCalculatorDisplay.setText(df.format(mCalculatorBrain.getResult()));
    // }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.my, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }



    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        String buttonPressed = ((Button) v).getText().toString();

        if (DIGITS.contains(buttonPressed)) {

            // digit was pressed
            if (userIsInTheMiddleOfTypingANumber) {

                if (buttonPressed.equals(".") && mCalculatorDisplay.getText().toString().contains(".")) {
                    // ERROR PREVENTION
                    // Eliminate entering multiple decimals
                } else {
                    mCalculatorDisplay.append(buttonPressed);
                }

            } else {

                if (buttonPressed.equals(".")) {
                    // ERROR PREVENTION
                    // This will avoid error if only the decimal is hit before an operator, by placing a leading zero
                    // before the decimal
                    mCalculatorDisplay.setText(0 + buttonPressed);
                } else {
                    mCalculatorDisplay.setText(buttonPressed);
                }

                userIsInTheMiddleOfTypingANumber = true;
            }

        } else {
            // operation was pressed
            if (userIsInTheMiddleOfTypingANumber) {

                mCalculatorBrain.setOperand(Double.parseDouble(mCalculatorDisplay.getText().toString()));
                userIsInTheMiddleOfTypingANumber = false;
            }

            mCalculatorBrain.performOperation(buttonPressed);
            mCalculatorDisplay.setText(df.format(mCalculatorBrain.getResult()));

        }

    }

    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        // Save variables on screen orientation change
        outState.putDouble("OPERAND", mCalculatorBrain.getResult());
        outState.putDouble("MEMORY", mCalculatorBrain.getMemory());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        // Restore variables on screen orientation change
        mCalculatorBrain.setOperand(savedInstanceState.getDouble("OPERAND"));
        mCalculatorBrain.setMemory(savedInstanceState.getDouble("MEMORY"));
        mCalculatorDisplay.setText(df.format(mCalculatorBrain.getResult()));
    }




}


<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/banda_bk"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"

    android:visibility="visible"
    tools:context=".MyActivity">

    <RelativeLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"


        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:id="@+id/rel_banda">

        <ImageView

            android:id="@+id/banda"

            android:visibility="visible"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/banda" />

        <ImageView

            android:id="@+id/ImageView1"
            android:layout_marginRight="92dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="52dp"
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/linearLayout4"
            android:visibility="gone"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:id="@+id/ImageView2"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/ImageView1"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/ImageView1"
            android:visibility="gone"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:id="@+id/ImageView3"
            android:layout_marginRight="41dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/ImageView2"
            android:visibility="gone"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:id="@+id/ImageView4"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:visibility="gone"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:id="@+id/ImageView5"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/ImageView4"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/ImageView4"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/ImageView4"
            android:visibility="gone"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:id="@+id/ImageView6"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/ImageView5"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/ImageView3"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/ImageView3"
            android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
            android:visibility="gone"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:id="@+id/ImageView7"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/ImageView6"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ImageView6"
            android:layout_marginLeft="22dp"
            android:visibility="gone"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:id="@+id/ImageView8"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/ImageView7"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ImageView2"
            android:visibility="gone"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:id="@+id/ImageView9"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/ImageView8"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ImageView8"
            android:layout_marginLeft="26dp"
            android:visibility="gone"/>


    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/row1"
            android:layout_width="600dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="bottom">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/b0"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight=".15"
                android:text="@string/b0"
                android:textSize="12sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/b1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_weight=".15"
                android:text="@string/b1"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:visibility="visible" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/b2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_weight=".15"
                android:text="@string/b2"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:visibility="visible" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/b3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_weight=".15"
                android:text="@string/b3"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:visibility="visible" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/b4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_weight=".15"
                android:text="@string/b4"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:visibility="visible" />


            <Button
                android:id="@+id/b5"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_weight=".15"
                android:text="@string/b5"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:visibility="visible" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/b6"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_weight=".15"
                android:text="@string/b6"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:visibility="visible" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/b7"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_weight=".15"
                android:text="@string/b7"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:visibility="visible" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/b8"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight=".15"
                android:text="@string/b8"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:visibility="visible" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/b9"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_weight=".15"
                android:text="@string/b9"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:visibility="visible" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/buttonClear"
                android:layout_width="33dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:text="@string/buttonClear"
                android:textSize="12sp" />


        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout4"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="33dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/printfirst"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="0" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/printsecond"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="0" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Raspuns_user"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_weight=".15"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:text="0"
            android:textColor="@color/textbody"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:textSize="10sp"
            android:text="Check" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Scorul"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Scor"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textColor="@color/textbody"
            android:textSize="10sp" />


    </LinearLayout>


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Ajutati spiridusii sa afle numarul total de piese lipsa. "
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:textSize="13dp"
        android:textColor="@color/textbody"

        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"  />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Handler handler = new Handler(); 
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() { 
         public void run() { 



       // YOUR CODE HERE


         } 
    }, 2000);
```

Where 2000 is 2 seconds delay/sleep in main thread.

Comment: The images are still overlapped if i use your code. I don't know why. It seems that they start in the same time

Comment: @ElenaE please put your entire activity and layout code in question

Comment: @ElenaE i am no expert on animations, give it some time, hopefully someone will answer ...

Answer (score 1):

You can use thread concept and in loop you can use sleep function for delay and you can write your code in it

```
thread = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                try {


                   YOUR FOR LOOP CODE HERE with this line "Thread.sleep(2000);"


                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "local Thread error", e);
                }
            }
        }
    };
    thread.start();
```

Comment: Or if your using animation file for animation then you can set animation timing in animation file also

Comment: I get this: android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.

Comment: you can use


try {
YOUR LOOP CODE INSIDE LOOP USE BELOW LINE INTO THE END OF YOUR LOOP
    Thread.sleep(2000);
}
catch (Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}

Comment: I don't understand. I still get this error:  Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.

Answer (score 0):

For create delay, you can use this code:

```
try {
    Thread.sleep(m); // m is millisecond, if m = 1000 ms then delay = 1 s
}
catch (InterruptedException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I use this

```
for(int j=0; j<i;j++) {
        final int finalJ = j;
        new android.os.Handler().postDelayed(
                new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {


                        imb_items[finalJ].startAnimation(translateAnim);


                        Log.i("tag", "This'll run 5000 milliseconds later");

                    }
                },
                5000 * j
        );
    }
```

the problem is that when when the second image starts moving, the first one stops and disappears. I would like all the images to continue their movement.

Answer (score 0):

This is the final solution:

```
for(int j=0; j<i;j++) {
   translateAnim[j].setStartOffset(5000*j);
   imb_items[j].startAnimation(translateAnim[j]);
}
```